# Is it possible to encrypt a bytes stream using PyCrypto?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pycrypto

I'm working on an app where users upload a file and the app processes it automatically for them. For data security, I want to encrypt these files. These files can be of varying sizes from small to very large (2MB to upwards of 30MB).
I came across PyCrypto as the de facto encryption/decryption package. The files are read into io.BytesIO() after being processed and then a file is created from the bytes stream. I was wondering if it is possible to 'encrypt' the bytes stream and then create the file. So that when I read the file into io.Bytes(), I can decrypt it and serve the file to the user.

Comment: Yes - have you tried it?

Comment: No. I tried it for PyAesCrypt but the package doesn't have a great user base. So I'm skeptical. I've not tried it using PyCrypto as in I don't know how to proceed. Can you write out an example or a snippet?

Comment: PyCrypto is abandoned and not works in Python 3.8, best candidate for this is pyca/cryptography.

Answer (score 1):

PyCrypto is abandoned and not works in Python 3.8, so best candidate for this work is `pyca/cryptography` but if you really need you can start with something like this:

```py
from io import BytesIO

from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

payload = BytesIO(b"SomeData")

# Implement PKCS7 padding.
block_size = 16
length = payload.getbuffer().nbytes
to_pad = block_size - length % block_size
payload.seek(length)
payload.write((chr(to_pad) * to_pad).encode("utf8"))
payload.seek(0)

# Setup the cipher.
iv = Random.new().read(block_size)
cipher = AES.new(
    "16-CHAR-LENGTH__",  # Some secret.
    mode=AES.MODE_CBC,
    IV=iv,
)

encrypted = cipher.encrypt(payload.read())
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response. I haven't tried this yet. I'll let you know if this works for me as soon as possible!